# In Scala, how can I avoid casting a function parameter?

Tags: scala

I want to have various *"flavors"* of a component, each that handles a different *"wire"* format (e.g. String, Byte array, etc.).  Example below.  The innards of the read() function aren't important.

Note that on use I need to cast parameter `"Heavy"` to `thing.WIRE` to work.  Since this is my top-level API I don't want the users to have to cast.  They've chosen the flavor when they call `FantasticThing.apply` (or accept the default).  After that I'd rather a cast not be needed.

How can I avoid the cast and have Scala realize that `read()` argument is a **String** based on `StringFlavor` being chosen?

```
trait Flavor {
  type WIRE
  def read[T](wire: WIRE)(implicit tt: TypeTag[T]): T
}

trait Maker {
  def make(): Flavor
}

object StringFlavor extends Maker {
  def make(): Flavor { type WIRE = String } = StringFlavor()
}

case class StringFlavor() extends Flavor {
  type WIRE = String
  def read[T](wire: String)(implicit tt: TypeTag[T]): T = {
    println(tt.tpe)
    if(tt.tpe =:= typeOf[Int]) {
      5.asInstanceOf[T]
    } else
      throw new Exception("Boom")
  }
}

object FantasticThing {
  def apply[WIRE](maker: Maker = StringFlavor): Flavor = maker.make()
}

object RunMe extends App {
  val thing: Flavor = FantasticThing(StringMaker)
  println(thing.read[Int]("Heavy".asInstanceOf[thing.WIRE])) // <-- How can I avoid this cast?
}
```

- Edit based on Luis Miguel's note:  I can't really add that type to FantasticThing.apply() or I'd lose pluggability.  I want users to easily select the Flavor they want.  I've refactored a bit to show this with a factory pattern, which does add the type info you suggested, but still unfortunately leaves me with a need to cast top-level.

If I provide a bunch of Flavors then users should be able to do something like:

```
val foo = FantasticThing(ByteArrayFlavor)
```

Comment: Could WIRE be moved to a type parameter on the class? Also, you should avoid casting everywhere, not just in your public API.

Comment: Well the problem is that here `def apply(): Flavor = StringFlavor()` you are losing all type information about `WIRE`. Thus, **Scala** has no way to know its underlying type is `String`, and your casting is _(in general terms)_ unsafe! - you can fix it doing something like `def apply(): Flavor { type WIRE = String } = StringFlavor()` then you can safely call `FantasticThing().read[Int]("Heavy")` since the compiler will guarantee that for that instance `Wire` equals `String`. Now, I am not posting this as an answer, because I am sure your real `apply` is more complex... care to expand it?

Comment: I don't see a "parameter "Heavy" anywhere in your snippet. Nor anything being cast to `thing.WIRE`

Comment: @Dima Greg removed that part on an edit addressing my _comment_, I have re-edited the question to include the missing part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `WIRE` a type parameter and propagate it through a type member or your `Maker` type. I.e:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

trait Flavor[WIRE] {
  def read[T](wire: WIRE)(implicit tt: TypeTag[T]): T
}

trait Maker {
  type O
  def make(): Flavor[O]
}

object StringMaker extends Maker {
  type O = String
  def make(): Flavor[O] = StringFlavor()
}

case class StringFlavor() extends Flavor[String] {
  def read[T](wire: String)(implicit tt: TypeTag[T]): T = {
    if(tt.tpe =:= typeOf[Int]) {
      5.asInstanceOf[T]
    } else
      throw new Exception("Boom")
  }
}

object FantasticThing {
  def apply(): Flavor[String] = StringMaker.make()
  def apply(maker: Maker): Flavor[maker.O]  = maker.make() // Path dependent type.
}

object RunMe extends App {
  val thing: Flavor[String] = FantasticThing(StringMaker)
  thing.read[Int]("Heavy") // res0: Int = 5
}
```

Edit:  Added no-arg apply() to this anwser.  If a default value for maker is used (e.g. StringMaker) you get a compile error because argument "Heavy" is now supposed to be type Maker.O.  Adding the no-arg apply solves this problem while providing the same experience to the caller.

Comment: @Greg I just did a quick edit to this answer adding explicit return type signatures just for clarity, as well as a comment explaining that such return type work as you want becasue it is a **_path dependent type_**.

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty to modify your code with the intention to show how *(what I understand of)* your problem can be solved using **typeclasses** and **type parameters**, instead of **type members**.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeOf}

implicit class Json(val underlying: String) extends AnyVal
implicit class Csv(val underlying: String) extends AnyVal

trait Flavor[W] {
  def read[T](wire: W)(implicit tt: TypeTag[T]): T
}

trait Maker[W] {
  def make(): Flavor[W]
}

object Maker {
  implicit val StringFlavorMaker: Maker[String] = new Maker[String] {
    override def make(): Flavor[String] = StringFlavor
  }

  implicit val JsonFlavorMaker: Maker[Json] = new Maker[Json] {
    override def make(): Flavor[Json] = JsonFlavor
  }

  implicit val CsvFlavorMaker: Maker[Csv] = new Maker[Csv] {
    override def make(): Flavor[Csv] = CsvFlavor
  }
}

case object StringFlavor extends Flavor[String] {
  override final def read[T](wire: String)(implicit tt: TypeTag[T]): T = {
    if(tt.tpe =:= typeOf[Int])
      0.asInstanceOf[T]
    else
      throw new Exception("Boom 1")
  }
}

case object JsonFlavor extends Flavor[Json] {
  override final def read[T](wire: Json)(implicit tt: TypeTag[T]): T = {
    if(tt.tpe =:= typeOf[Int])
      3.asInstanceOf[T]
    else
      throw new Exception("Boom 2")
  }
}

case object CsvFlavor extends Flavor[Csv] {
  override final def read[T](wire: Csv)(implicit tt: TypeTag[T]): T = {
    if(tt.tpe =:= typeOf[Int])
      5.asInstanceOf[T]
    else
      throw new Exception("Boom 3")
  }
} 

object FantasticThing {
  def apply[W](implicit maker: Maker[W]): Flavor[W] = maker.make()
}
```

Then you can create and user any flavour *(given there is an implicit maker in scope)* this way.

```
val stringFlavor = FantasticThing[String]
// stringFlavor: Flavor[String] = StringFlavor

stringFlavor.read[Int]("Heavy")
// res0: Int = 0

val jsonFlavor = FantasticThing[Json]
// jsonFlavor: Flavor[Json] = JsonFlavor

jsonFlavor.read[Int]("{'heavy':'true'}")
// res1: Int = 3

val csvFlavor = FantasticThing[Csv]
// csvFlavor: Flavor[Csv] = CsvFlavor

csvFlavor.read[Int]("Hea,vy")
// res2: Int = 0
```

In general, is better to stay off of **type members**, since they are more complex and used for more advanced stuff like **path dependent types**.
Let me know in the comments if you have any doubt.

---

***DISCLAIMER:** I am bad with type members (still learning about them), that may motivate me to use different alternatives. - In any case, I hope you can apply something similar to your real problem.*.

Comment: I like the elegance of the typeclass-based approach.  One limitation would be if I have other types that are String-derived, e.g. JSON or CSV.  In those cases the compiler complains about ambiguous implicits.  As long as the actual types for W is distinct, this approach is would work well.

Comment: @Greg I see, I know gogstad's answer is what you needed, but I just wanted to show _(just for the record and if someone else had a similar problem)_, that you could use wrapper classes to make that work with **typeclasses**.